# How do I access files downloaded through Telegram?

Tags: iphone, ios

I Googled it, but haven't found anything. Basically I've downloaded a couple of files through Telegram. I can see them in Telegram settings- storage usage. But how do I get access to them and transfer them to iCloud Drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I transferred them using AirDrop to my mac.

Answer (score 1):

Open the file, say PDF, in the chat, and use the share icon in the top right to save it to Files etc.

[image: share icon]

You could use telegram for Mac too.

Answer (score 0):

When using the Mac app for telegram, open the file and click on 'Download' icon, it will save to Downloads folder.

Comment: Thanks mate, I’ve been waiting for this answer for 3 years…

Answer (score -1):

1. Launch Telegram on your iOS device
2. Go to Settings and choose Advanced
3. Select Local Storage and you will see the path where the save files are stored on your iOS

[Source](https://www.filelocations.com/where-does-telegram-save-files-android-ios-pc/)

Comment: The question is about how to access these files. Once a user knows the path on their iPhone, how can they access the files?

Comment: There is no Advanced in Settings...